# Neo4j: Could someone "translate" this code snippet for me?

Tags: neo4j

I'm sorry if I don't follow best practice here, but I just can't understand (and therefore of course also not recreate in a new version of Neo4j) whatever this snippet is supposed to do :(

Out of interest, I started my journey in Neo4j and concluded the intro classes and wanted to recreate some projects to become more fluent with this interesting technology.
But I can't wrap my head around this exercise from the "What's cooking" example:

```
// Construct lists of node ids of ingredients, 
// grouped by node ids of recipes 
MATCH (r:Recipe)-[:CONTAINS_INGREDIENT]->(ingredient)
WITH {item:id(r), categories: collect(id(ingredient))} as userData
WITH collect(userData) as data
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard.stream(data)
YIELD item1, item2, count1, count2, intersection, similarity

// Look up nodes by node id
WITH algo.asNode(item1) AS from, 
     algo.asNode(item2) AS to, 
     similarity, intersection 
RETURN from.name, from.id, to.name, to.id, intersection, similarity
ORDER BY similarity DESC
LIMIT 20
```

when I try to update the outdated *algo.similarity.jaccard()* with *gds.nodeSimilarity.stream* as well as *algo.asNode()* with *gds.asNode()*, I still fail after the **YIELD** statement where the console tells me, that it just doesn't find *item1* (and therefore will also not find *item2*).

**EDIT**: I'm running with Neo4j version 4.2.5 and GDS 1.5.2

I hope someone could help me to understand what's gone wrong!

BR,
Dan

Comment: what is your GDS version and Neo4j version?

Comment: Hi @jose_bacoy, please excuse my forgetfulness! I use Neo4j 4.2.5 and GDS 1.5.2. BR, Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that your example is from the older algorithms library, not the current GDS library. Here's a breakdown of what the example code is doing.

Start by matching recipes with the ingredients they contain.

```
// Construct lists of node ids of ingredients, 
// grouped by node ids of recipes 
MATCH (r:Recipe)-[:CONTAINS_INGREDIENT]->(ingredient)
```

At this point, we have a tall result set consisting pairs of `r` nodes for recipes and `ingredient` nodes for ingredients.

```
WITH {item:id(r), categories: collect(id(ingredient))} as userData
```

Now we have transformed the results so that we have one map per recipe. The map has two key-value pairs. The `item` key points to the recipe node's id. The `categories` key points to a list of all of the ids for the ingredient nodes.

```
WITH collect(userData) as data
```

We transform the results again from many rows with one map per row to a single row. This row contains a list called `data` that holds all the maps. This is the format that algo.similarity.jaccard.stream expects as input. Now we can call the algorithm.

```
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard.stream(data)
YIELD item1, item2, count1, count2, intersection, similarity
```

The algorithm outputs item1 and item2. These are Neo4j's internal node ids. Those ids have no meaning outside of Neo4j, so we want to convert them back into nodes by calling `algo.asNode`

```
// Look up nodes by node id
WITH algo.asNode(item1) AS from, 
     algo.asNode(item2) AS to, 
     similarity, intersection
```

Now we can return the node properties that are interesting to us.

```
RETURN from.name, from.id, to.name, to.id, intersection, similarity
ORDER BY similarity DESC
LIMIT 20
```

To do something similar in the current Graph Data Science library, you can use the [Node Similarity algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/node-similarity/). Instead of expecting a list of maps, the GDS algorithm accepts an in-memory graph projection as input. Create an in-memory graph called `recipe-graph` that contains the `Recipe` and `Ingredient` nodes and the `CONTAINS_INGREDIENT` relationships.

```
CALL gds.graph.create('recipe-graph', ["Recipe", "Ingredient"], 'CONTAINS_INGREDIENT')
```

Then, pass that graph to the `nodeSimilarity` algorithm.

```
CALL gds.nodeSimilarity.stream('recipe-graph')
 YIELD node1, node2, similarity
 WITH gds.util.asNode(node1) AS r1, 
    gds.util.asNode(node2) AS r2, similarity
 WHERE r1:Recipe and r1:Recipe
 RETURN r1.name as recipe1, r2.name as recipe2, similarity
 ORDER BY similarity DESCENDING, r1.name, r2.name
 LIMIT 20
```

Finally, drop the in-memory graph you created.

```
CALL gds.graph.drop('recipe-graph')
```

If you don't want to create and drop a named graph, it's also possible to call the algorithm on an [anonymous graph](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/anonymous-graph/).

Comment: Dear Nathan,

thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question in detail and most importantly educate me in the same process!
I would only have two questions remaining.
1. I tried to “clean up” the output for the duplicate recipes (a -> b & b -> a), but all my tries of multiple WHERE clauses led to nothing.
2. (The more important question) Do you have any suggestion where I can get any kind of training for Neo4j/Cypher? I followed the training of Neo4js Graph Academy, but I have the feeling that Graph Academy is mostly scratching on the surface.
Thank you again!
BR,
Dan

Comment: Hi Dan. I'm glad it was helpful! If you wanted to keep the first recipe name alphabetically in each recipe pair, you could add this to the existing where clause: and r1.name < r2.name.

Comment: I think Graph Academy is a great way to get started with Cypher. To go deeper, here's the official resource list. https://neo4j.com/developer/resources/ There are instructor lead trainings available. https://neo4j.com/events/category/training/. If you can get to Austin, TX, in June 2022, Graph Connect will be a great learning opportunity. https://www.graphconnect.com/ The Neo4j Online Meetup offers good free content on a regular basis. https://www.meetup.com/Neo4j-Online-Meetup/ There might be a local Meetup near you (I organize the Kansas City Graph Databases Meetup).

Comment: I can't express my gratitude enough! The Graph Connect Event might be a stretch for me (living in Austria) but I will try to persuade my boss that sending me there makes a lot of sense ;) Thank you as well for the links with the material - I will study my way trough it. Thanks again and have a great one, BR, Dan